# Rails how to edit and delete comments created comments with cookie authication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want my visitors to be able to edit or delete their comment up too 5-10 min after they created it.

How should I authenticate this with a session or cookie?
My comment controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.xml

  # GET /comments/new
  # GET /comments/new.xml
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @comment }
    end
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.xml
  def create
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
    params[:comment][:ip] = request.remote_ip
    @comment = @blog.comments.create!(params[:comment])
    redirect_to @blog
  end

  # PUT /comments/1
  # PUT /comments/1.xml
  def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
        format.html { redirect_to(admin_comments_path, :notice => 'Comment was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @comment.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.xml
  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(admin_comments_url, :notice => 'Indlæg slettet') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of the time limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store the saved comment's id in the session and then at the time of delete or update, check the session for the comment's id and compare the current-time with the comment's created_at... this can go in a filter method.

Also, you can move the code of finding the comment with id in a filter and can follow DRY.

Here it goes:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :get_blog
  before_filter :get_comment, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authorize_comment, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  private

  def get_blog
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
  end

  def get_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def authorize_comment
    unless @comment
      flash[:error] = "Comment Not Found" 
      redirect_to @blog and return
    else
      # checks whether the comment is there in sessions' recent_comments 
      # if true, it means, this comment was created by the same visitor who is now attempting to delete/update it again
      if session[:recent_comments].include?(@comment.id)

        # now check if the comment is editable w.r.t time or not
        if @comment.created_at < 10.minutes.ago
          # if true, it means comment can no longer be updated/deleted
          # if you wish you can now remove this from the session's recent_comments
          session[:recent_comments].delete(@comment.id)
          flash[:error] = "Sorry, you can not change this comment now"
          redirect_to @blog and return
        else
          # it means comment can be edited/updated
          return true
        end
      else
        flash[:error] = "Sorry, you can not change this comment now"
        redirect_to @blog and return
      end
    end
  end

  public


  def new
    @comment = Comment.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @comment }
    end
  end


  def edit
  end

  def create    
    params[:comment][:ip] = request.remote_ip
    @comment = @blog.comments.create!(params[:comment])

    unless session[:recent_comments].is_a?(Array)
      session[:recent_comments] = []
    end
    session[:recent_comments] << @comment.id

    redirect_to @blog
  end

  def update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
        format.html { redirect_to(admin_comments_path, :notice => 'Comment was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @comment.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(admin_comments_url, :notice => 'Indlæg slettet') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```